# Create instances of namedtuples as database records with loop

Tags: python, numpy, namedtuple

I was wondering whether it is possible to instantiate namedtuples within a loop. The problem I am having is that I have individual files (>500), which each should be an instance of a namedtuple and I would like to use the filename, to access records.
e.g. say I have a namedtuple with three attributes

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd
record_ids=["record1","record2"]
reads=namedtuple("reads", "id length text")
for record in record_ids:
    records=pd.read_table(record+".txt",dtype=None, header='infer')
    text=records.iloc[0:100]
    entry=[record,len(text),text)
    varname=reads._make(entry)
```

Where record_ids are the filenames saved in a list.
I would like varname to be the filename. So if my file is record1.txt, that I can access record1.length anywhere.
My questions are:
1) Is this a sensible approach? I need to perform mathematical operations on larger datasets, this is not for record keeping.
2) Is this possible? Or is there a more pythonic alternative?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Comment: A minor point, but you could also use `reads(*entry)` to create a named tuple from `entry`.

Comment: It's not easy, nor encouraged, to make variably named objects.  Normally we would collect the `reads` objects in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for both the comments! If I add the reads `reads` objects in a list/dict, could I still call them individually? As in, if I use `record` as a dict key, and the `reads` object as value, can I still access individual fields (say `text`) from a specific object? Thank you again!

Comment: `adict['record1'].text` should work.

Comment: @hpaulj Great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to varname might run you into problems, especially as it won't iterate and you'll end up with one referencable tuple, instead of the large list of tuples you want to be able to look through.

You might want to consider instantiating each reads() class into a collection of objects.

For a list of objects, the object doesn't need a name, so you don't need a variable, just the collection list type will suffice. The penalty for later iterating through the records is not being able to reference one if you know the record id. Naming each one with a variable would be exponentially worse.

The solution to preventing variable bloat and being able to reference each reads object by the record id is a dictionary. This seems consistent with how your code now tries to reveal the identity of the tuple by you later having to scan through to read the record id, which, in your case, is not yet made unique because all you've attached to it is '.txt', and your id values appear to be in a list. That list appears as though it might benefit from a list comprehension.

In any case, for a named reference to the record, the dictionary would be labeled with a variable. Your record id could optionally be in the class, in case you move a record to a list and detach from the dictionary key for some reason...
With the record id serving as the dictionary key, the following roughly approximates what you'd end up with for the data model:
dict_varname = {'record_id_unique': }

Your prototype namedtuple 'reads' can be reused using the namedtuple ._replace() method. The prototype never has to go into the list, it just has to be accessible as a functional blueprint. It's already labeled as the variable 'reads' in your example. You could name the variable something different, but it works that way. The class name is in quotes inside the parentheses of the namedtuple declaration.

```
from collections import namedtuple as nt
reads = nt('reads', ('id', 'length', 'text'))
```

Some of the items of that prototype can be reused, even on instance creation.

```
my_record_list = []
for _ in range(len(list_of_records)):
    my_record_list.append(reads._replace(reads, id='record'+_, length=len(the_text), text=the_text))
```

._replace will keep values you don't overwrite, making a flexible bunch of defaults of the values you first ascribe to the prototype (the declaration/instance of the class reads labeled 'reads').

```
my_record_dict = {}
data = ['so_long', 'lots_of_data']
    for recordid in recordid_list:
        for data in recordid_datalist:
            my_record_dict[recordid] = reads('reads', length=len(data[0]), text=data[1])
```

To read the data, you can iterate over the keys to extract the object (value) and read the field you want from it. You can also more easily select a record without having to search through all the records to find the tuple index for the value you want to find. The dictionary keys are immutable, and these hash values can be more quickly found than iterating through a list's object's indices.

If you've followed so far on the default values, the rest of this 'fixes' the problems from above, that is, relying on reads to ._replace values and create new instances in a loop without repeating all values. Shown above, you can do the following, but ._replace and the syntax works in a flaky way if you do, namely, by requiring all values. See above for how 'reads' is a value in the new instance. Tricky, huh?

```
reads._replace(reads (id='123', length=999999, text='why?'))
```

Better to create an instance which then holds your default values, making your new instances from it:

```
proto = reads('123', 999999, 'why not') # your default values on which to build
print(proto)
```

A final example of making under a label. Remove the label when you want to append a new instance using replaced values from within a loop:

```
k = proto._replace(id=34)
print(k)
```

I hope this helps.